# How we can implement in-app purchase for book purchasing app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement the in-app purchase feature for one of my applications. On that app, users can purchase ebooks, and purchased books will add to the library. After that, users can always read the book with no time limit/ no expiry and no need to pay again for the same book.

I have chosen the Non-Consumable type in-app feature from the list. But on the in-app purchase part, the price part is a problem for me. The price tier is a fixed one, and in my case, the book's prices are different.

**Following are my doubts:**

1. How can I add different prices for my books when purchasing. Is there any option for passing the amount when purchasing a book on the project configuration (code behind) part?
2. I am using xamarin forms for the development of the project. What are the configurations we need to make on the project side?
3. For the new in-app property I am getting missing metadata status, I didn't accept the latest agreement, is that status because of this?
4. How much is the amount/percentage cut to Apple for purchases? Is the cut applied for all purchases, or cut will apply only when a particular limit is reached?

I am doing the in-app feature for the first time, from research I didn't get an idea about this.

Comment: For the first item I think the best option is to fetch the books/prices from a server, then convert them to a collection of items and displaying them in a `ListView` or `CollectionView`

Comment: @JuanSturla In my app, the book prices are added. my question is how I can use that price when purchasing? In in-app purchase, the price tier is a fixed one, and in my case, the book's prices are different.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=in+app+purchase+with+variable+pricing+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason So variable pricing is not possible in apple in-app purchases?

Comment: I have no idea.   But I do know that this question has been asked multiple times before.  Please avoid asking duplicate questions